# My prefix is a part of your head, My infix is the sound of the dead

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix is a part of your head
- My suffix saves a place for you
- My infix is the sound of the dead
- My whole is white and also blue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's

> facebook

My prefix is a part of your head

> face

My suffix saves a place for you

> to book

My infix is the sound of the dead

> "boo", sound that ghosts make in movies

My whole is white and also blue

> The logo of facebook is white and blue